# Выборка данных из нескольких таблиц в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Как запросом получить данные из двух таблиц? Есть классы `Patient` и `Service`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @OneToOne
    private Patient patient;

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    public Service(String text, double price) {
        this.text = text;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Service() {}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "fam")
    private String fam;

    @Column(name = "im")
    private String im;

    @Column(name = "ot")
    private String ot;

    @Column(name = "bdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date bdate;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "patient") //Указывает на переменную в классе Service
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Service service;

    public Patient(String fam, String im, String ot, Date bdate, Service service) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.im = im;
        this.ot = ot;
        this.bdate = bdate;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Patient() {}
}
```

Запросом ниже выбираю данные в список объектов. Но как вывести в `System.out.println()` реальные данные из полученной коллекции?

```
Query query6 = session.createQuery("from Patient p, Service s where p = s.patient");
List<Object> list11 = query6.list();
```

Или есть способ иначе?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно не получается. Получение данных или вывод их в System.out.println()?

Comment: Вывод данных в консоль. Размер списка после получения данных равен 1. Т.е. вроде как получается брать данные, но как их вытаскивать не знаю.

Comment: Query query6 = session.createQuery("from Service s");
List<Service> list11 = query6.list();
System.out.println( list11.get(0) );
System.out.println( list11.get(0).patient );

Comment: Сработало а по какому принципу нужно так выбирать? Эти связи один к одному, один ко многим еще не очень понял, поэтому непонятно как заработало.

Comment: У Вас java объект Service имеет ссылку на объект patient. Вы говорите в select - хочу объект Service и hibernate Вам его загружает и patien объект, тоже загружает как часть объекта Service. Если у Вас будет связь OneToMany, то загрузится список объектов Patient, как часть объекта Service. Дальше Вы работаете в java.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.